# What type of battery terminal is this?

Tags: batteries

I am interested in a LiFePO4 Lithium Iron Phosphate battery product and wonder if anyone knows what type of terminal connector the battery has. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Perhaps some variation of Anderson Powerpole, but generally you do not want to buy things which do not have meaningful specifications; a reputable supplier would tell you what the connector is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Anderson Powerpole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson_Powerpole)

> Powerpole connectors are available with current ratings up to 180
> amperes. The size most commonly used is the 15/30/45 ampere-rated
> variety. These sizes all use the same plastic housing in multiple
> colors, differing only in the metal contact inserted into the housing
> (selected based on the ampacity and wire size). The colors can be
> used to signify signal types (power, speaker, logic, microphone audio,
> etc.) or differing voltages. Powerpole connectors can be attached side
> to side and also stacked on top of each other to make, for example,
> four connections with one plug insertion.